# Rspec & Factory Girl: Create one record to use before all describe blocks in a Model test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

For some reason I'm finding it difficult to find an answer for this simple question.

I'm testing a Movie model:

```
RSpec.describe Movie, type: :model do


  describe 'some_method' do
     it "should do something" do
     end
  end

  describe 'some_other_method' do
    it "should do something else" do
    end
  end

end
```

And I can build a movie like `build(:movie)`, but I don't know where I should put that. Outside of the describe blocks, it throws an error:

> undefined method `build' for #

But if I put it inside the describe blocks, it's not very DRY since I'd need to do it for each block.

How can I create one line of code that creates a new movie before each describe block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `let`:

```
RSpec.describe Movie, type: :model do

  let(:movie) { build(:movie) }

  describe 'an awesome movie' do
     it "is awesome" do
       expect(movie.awesome?).to be true
     end
  end
end
```

The `let` block is executed in the context of the example, so methods defined by `let` are available in the test. This is also true of `before`:

```
before do
  movie.awesome = true
end
```

Statements in `before` are executed before the examples within the describe block. Note that `before` and `let` can also work with a nested `describe`, in which case they are defined for any context nested within the `describe`.